# How to Set My Script Results As Rows

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am running the below Powershell command in order to get the resource usage of each VM.

```
Measure-VM -Name * | select-object -property VMName, MeteringDuration, AverageProcessorUsage, AverageMemoryUsage, TotalDiskAllocation
```

My concern is that the result set is being returned as rows instead of having each properties as columns.

RESULT

- VMName
- MeteringDuration
- ...
- ...

EXPECTATION
VMName MeteringDuration ... ...

Since I want to copy the results into excel, I was hoping there's a way to mitigate this. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell will make a best guess at the format when it displays output. If you're exporting to Excel, CSV, any other format, what you see on the screen plays no part at all.

That is, if you have this in the console:

```
Get-Thing

Property1: one
Property2: two
Property3: three
```

Running this will still be perfectly normal:

```
Get-Thing | Export-Csv Things.csv
```

Just avoid trying to build a file using Format-* and redirect and all will be well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is it possible to integrate the script that you indicated above to the script that I am using?

Also, can Powershell still perform the export even if no MS Office is installed in the server?

Comment: Export-Csv will always work, it has no external dependencies. Writing to a full-fat excel file is harder and needs other things. For example, I have a writer based around the epplus library, other implementations may use Excel itself (and therefore require Office). Export-Csv is simpler :)  `Measure-VM -Name * | select-object -property VMName, MeteringDuration, AverageProcessorUsage, AverageMemoryUsage, TotalDiskAllocation | Export-Csv C:\Temp\YourFile.csv`

Comment: While you have exported it to csv you can easily split it by delimiter in MS Excel. You cannot export your data to XLS/XLSX document without external DLL's or Com object that will require MS Excel to be installed.